# server side redirection without the intervention of the browser

Tags: c#-3.0

I've got a website replicated on different severs. When one of the servers is busy the requests must be redirected to another server which has less load. The problem is that while redirecting, the browser should not be aware of the redirection. The server itself redirects the request to another server which has less load (**by some means it should check the load of the server to which the request is being redirected**) using server-side redirect and then receives the response from that server and then sends the same response to the client. Could anyone suggest me the possible code and help me out in this regard? Thanks in advance..............

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the only way to do this is to setup network load balancing at the server level. Here's some links:

- [Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758834%28WS.10%29.aspx)
- [How to setup](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/213/network-load-balancing/)
- [How to configure NICs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323431)
- [Configure ASP.Net to share state/keys across servers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LoadBalancingAndASPNET.aspx)